# Why does this transaction results in only 2 unspent output (and no spent output)?

Tags: output

[This transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/7253e818ba712f98654ca1fc03191027e590dcac06eda36e7b13dc835422b67a?show_adv=true) is from one of the latest block. However I don't understand why it seems to be just dividing a single transaction without being spent and transferred to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why it seems to be just dividing a single
>   transaction without being spent and transferred to someone else

Only Unspent tx i.e UTXO could be spent, and here in your case [this](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/7253e818ba712f98654ca1fc03191027e590dcac06eda36e7b13dc835422b67a)  tx is UTXO which after spending to addresses

```
13MDsVCs3AvSxZxjWUwty2gthPAXkYf6wb - (Unspent) 0.00928291 BTC
1CPp812W35rarR45CS6EYxdC4JazR4H9Wn - (Spent) 0.00231133 BTC
```

now becomes spent tx

> Why does this transaction results in only 2 unspent output (and no
>   spent output)?

This is because lets say this is  your address: `1CPp812W35rarR45CS6EYxdC4JazR4H9Wn` where you want `0.00231133` `btc`, so its one of the output address.
So after sending 0.00231133 to your address leftover balance i.e 0.00928291 need to be stored some where so in that case  `13MDsVCs3AvSxZxjWUwty2gthPAXkYf6wb` becomes your change address where remaning btc left after spending utxo is sent. Thats why you have 2 unspent op

Comment: I swear to god when I was posting this questions, the page was showing that both outputs are unspent. Now one of them became spent. Is there some kind of delay here?

Comment: no there is no delay as such, what happened is when you posted the question 13MDsVCs3AvSxZxjWUwty2gthPAXkYf6wb was unspent only, but later in tx: a314d0b1f3f08a07cccca64865d4fe4654b3fe86dabd019438895d2dd0f75d0d this address was used as Vin which result it to be spent in tx: 7253e818ba712f98654ca1fc03191027e590dcac06eda36e7b13dc835422b67a

Comment: Understood. the output only became spent if it is used in the subsequent tx. But let's not talk about the subsequent transaction and just look at this tx (7253e818ba712f98654ca1fc03191027e590dcac06eda36e7b13dc835422b67a) alone. Why will the user want to make a transaction when the outputs are not spent immediately? (I assume that no amount is sent to anyone else at the end of this transaction)

Comment: Its because your transaction is “unconfirmed” until the next block is created. Once that block is created and the new transaction is verified and included in that block, the transaction will have one confirmation. Approximately every ten minutes thereafter, a new block is created and the transaction is reconfirmed by the Bitcoin network. It is common for six confirmations to be required which takes about an hour.

Comment: I don't get the link here. Why will the user want to make a transaction when the outputs are not spent immediately? Only to be truly spent on the subsequent transaction? is it like a test run to see if he can do transaction? but that will cost him transaction fee no?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cryptoKTM, I figured this out: the biggest misconception I had with regards to unspent transaction output is that, the word 'unspent' actually is according to the recipient's perspective, not to the sender's perspective.

This means that if a transaction results in multiple outputs that says 'unspent', it means all of these outputs have not been used up, or spent by any recipient. It DOES NOT mean that the sender (who has the inputs' addresses) did not spend and transfer the bitcoin successfully.